# Как указать кодировку для функции mail()?

Tags: php

Как указать кодировку для функции mail()? А то одни иероглефи приходят, тело письма при этом отображается нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как отправляем? скорее всего вот это поможет избавиться от кракозябров в имени отправителя

```
$headers ="From: =?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($mfrom_name) ."?= <$mfrom_mail>\n";
```

и это -- в теме письма

```
mail($mailto, "=?utf-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?=", $body, $headers);
```

Comment: Спасибо помогло! Использовал второй вариант.

Comment: лучше и про имя отправителя незабывать, врдуг там когданить окажется имя на русском языке? :)

Comment: если ответ на Ваш вопрос дан, то примите ответ и закройте вопрос. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую посылать письмо в формате HTML. Это избавит от проблем с кодировкой.

Comment: причем тут хтмл? тело письма в норме...